# How to find time spent per user per application in Google Apps?

Tags: reporting-services, google-analytics, google-api, google-apps

Is it possible to obtain some kind of statistics on which user spent how much time on which application when they log into Google Apps?
Applications example would be gmail/sites/talk etc.,

Comment: It is like user logs into the google apps site and then the tracker begins tracking the time spent per application.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "[Analytics for Google Apps](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113173)" to analyze traffic limited to your sites, documents, presentations and spreadsheets.
Afaik, it's not possible to monitor gmail and gtalk.

Comment: note that the link you point to has been long retired. Its not possible to " track documents presentations and spreadsheets", only google sites which is not what the op is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot measure how much time each user spends on each google app. However you can run domain usage reports. there is an API for reports (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started) and there are also many built-in reports in the google apps console (https://admin.google.com).
 This help article summarizes it: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6000239?hl=en